# Sessions is not performing the task

Tags: php, session

```
function display_message()
{
    if (isset($_SESSION['message'])) {
        echo $_SESSION['message'];
        unset($_SESSION['message']);
    }
}
```

Why when I remove the unset the code work but the problem that the message is not removed , so I need to keep can anyone tell me why the code is not work

## Note

That i use session_start()

Comment: try not unset(), but ```$_SESSION['message'] = NULL;```

Comment: may be the session is closed ( via session_write_close() ) before you try to unset it's data, if it is, then the modification is ignored.

Comment: $_SESSION['message'] = NULL; still not working

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be tested by others.
Please see: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn't Work”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616)

Answer (score 1):

I have faced that issue before but i fixed it in this way  and tested it working in local environment

```
function display_message()
{

   if (isset($_SESSION['message'])) {
     echo $_SESSION['message'];
   }

   unset($_SESSION['message']);
}
```

Instead of using unset function inside  if statement, move it to outside.

Answer (score 0):

You can unset instead,destroy your session whit down code.
The purpose is the name session.

```
session_start();

    $_SESSION['name'] = "name";
    echo "<br>" . $_SESSION['name'] . "<br>";

    $_SESSION['family'] = "family";
    $_SESSION['name'] = null;




    test the code--------------------------------------test the code

    if (isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
        echo "The code didnt work<br>";
        echo $_SESSION['name'];
    } else {
        echo "The code is working<br>";
    }

    echo $_SESSION['family'];
```

Comment: `session_destroy()` removes all session data

Comment: So it's not the answer to the question. OP wants to remove only S_SESSION['message']